# O que preciso mudar nesse método para funcionar corretamente?

Tags: java

Esse método procura, pelo telefone do Cliente, as Reservas que estão feitas nele.

O Cliente pode ter mais de uma reserva, mas o método só está mostrando a primeira reserva registrada no cliente. O que devo mudar no código para mostrar todas?

```
public void pesquisaImovelPorCliente(String telefoneCliente)
{
    boolean localizouImovel = false;//variável auxiliar para verificar se a busca teve sucesso

    for(int i = 0; i< qtdeReservas; i++)
    {
        if(ListaDeReservas[i].cliente.getTelefone().equals(telefoneCliente)){

            ListaDeReservas[i].exibeDados();

            //busca teve sucesso-
            localizouImovel = true;

            break;
        }
    }

    if(!localizouImovel)//se não localizou
      System.out.println ("Não foi localizado nenhuma acomodação para este telefone.");
}
```

Comment: Depois de ver a resposta correta, se puder altere o título da pergunta. Isso ajudará usuários que podem ter o mesmo problema que você no futuro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse `break` está fazendo o fluxo sair do for. Elimine-o!

Comment: Foi mais rápido que eu =)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Evite usar *flags* tanto quanto possível, toda vez que tem uma *flag* em um código provavelmente ele está mal escrito. Neste caso seria melhor fazer o seguinte.

```
public void pesquisaImovelPorCliente(String telefoneCliente) {
    for (int i = 0; i< qtdeReservas; i++) {
        if (ListaDeReservas[i].cliente.getTelefone().equals(telefoneCliente)) {
            ListaDeReservas[i].exibeDados();
        } else {
            System.out.println ("Não foi localizado nenhuma acomodação para este telefone.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Tem casos que eliminar a *flag* pode tornar o código mais confuso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Break.java).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!